# Setting the HTML-Tag to position:relative

Tags: html, css, position

I want a div-container to be positioned at the very bottom of my page but using `position:absolute` it seems the container is simply positioned n pixels from top. If I set the HTML-tag to `position:relative` it works as intended.

Is it good practice to set the HTML-tag to `position:relative`?

```css
html {
  background: #FAFAFA;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #CCC;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#sidebar_bottom {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #313131;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
}

p {
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="page_wrapper">
  <div id="main">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore
      eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
      euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
      velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis
      eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim
      ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.</p>

  </div>
  <div id="sidebar_bottom">
    <p>This container should be at the very bottom, not here!</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Depends upon a lot of things...

Comment: Can you give an example of how it goes wrong, in a jsFiddle for example? I can't imagine `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` not working without tricks like that, unless there are other things interfering.

Comment: @MrLister I made a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fiddle, the `body` isn't positioned. So the elements that are absolutely positioned are positioned relatively to the `html`, not to the `body`.

And the `html` is 100% high, as high as the window.

Solution: give body `position:relative`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/UYLWd/5/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is it better to give <BODY> position:relative and not <HTML>?

Comment: Yes. You should really refrain from giving `<html>` too many styles. Some browsers (admittedly, older ones) don't like styles on their `<html>` a lot. In this particular case, would the browser know what the position would be relative to? `<html>` is the root element, so it doesn't have a parent to be relative to.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the HTML and BODY have the size of the content on your page. When you have only a div - the HTML is stretched to that size.

Add this to your CSS:

```
html { height:100%; }
body { min-height:100%; }
```

This will make your html the size of your browser viewport and will set the body to a height of at least that viewport.
Then try again using

```
#yourdiv {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

on your div

After seeing the jsFiddle, if the #footer element is the one that has to go to the end, do this:

```
#page_wrapper {
 position:relative;
}
#footer {
 position:absolute;
}
```

The container of the element you want to position must always have a set position other than static. This is a general rule.

Comment: That's how I usually solved this. Now I believe there has to be some mistake

Comment: Can you provide an example in jsFiddle ?

Comment: I suppose #footer has to go to the end?
set #page_wrapper { position:relative; } and #footer { position:absolute; }

Comment: No, actually #sidebar_bottom has to go to the end. Have a look at the fiddle again. I removed every unnecessary bit so it's less confusing.

Comment: Right now.. #sidebar_bottom is on the very bottom (in the jsFiddle)

Comment: It's at the bottom of the window but not at the bottom of the page. Scroll down to see what I mean.

Answer (score -1):

It depends, if you position you body tag relative with a width of 100% and a height of 100%, you will be able to use absolute positioning without any risks.

```
body(position:absolute}
#Container {position:absolute; bottom:0;}
```

To explain the difference between absolute and relative, picture a block, if it is positioned relative, your absolute div inside it will use the relative div as a container for top and left positioning.

Comment: This will not work because the body will have a width and height of the HTML tag, which has the width of the page and the height of the inserted div. In order for his attempt to work, HTML needs to be set to a width of 100% of the browser's viewport